# How to make Android listen to requests from server using spring

Tags: java, android, spring, rest, service

I have an Android app which communicates with my server by using Android Spring framework. For this I simply use the following piece of code:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();    
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());    
String result = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class, "SpringSource");
```

and it returns me a String from the server. Note that in the server I'm also using spring Framework, so this request is sent to a controller class which does the logic and returns the String requested for the app.

Now I'm trying to do the opposite. I would like to send requests from the server to de app. For example, I would like to, at any moment, send a String to my app.

Is there a way to do it using Spring framework for android? If not, what is the alternative way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Google Cloud Messaging for Android is what you need, if you are looking for push notifications. Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) and this [link](http://lukaszbudnik.blogspot.in/2011/11/ios-and-android-push-notifications-from.html) (Even though this speaks about an older version) for more information

Comment: Thanks! I could do it using GCM! :)